# How to save multiple username and password in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cookies, local-storage

First - I know not to keep passwords and logins that way. I am only doing this as a task.

So, i need to save username and password from register form, and next use it in login form.
How i can do this with only html and JS?

Now i have something like that:

```
let user_name = document.getElementById("username");
let user_paswrd = document.getElementById("password");


let store_data = () => {
  let input_username = localStorage.setItem("username", user_name.value);
  let input_password = localStorage.setItem("password", user_paswrd.value);

};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gcu78z20/

it's saving username and password in localstorage, but I need to save all registered username and password. Then in login menu get it back when login. How can I do it? It is better to do this with localstore or cookie?

IMPORTANT INFORMATION
this form will only be opened locally. The website will not be on the web.

Comment: @Spectric the question says "I know not to keep passwords and logins that way. I am only doing this as a task."

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data as an array.

```js
if(!localStorage.getItem("credentials")) localStorage.setItem("credentials", JSON.stringify([]));

var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("credentials"));
console.log(arr)

let user_name = document.getElementById("username");
let user_paswrd = document.getElementById("password");

let store_data = () => {
  credentials.push({username: user_name, password: user_paswrd});
  localStorage.setItem("credentials", JSON.stringify(arr))

};
```

```html
<input id="username" type='text' placeholder="username"><br>
<input id="password" type='password' placeholder="password"><br>
<button onclick="store_data">Submit</button>
```

Comment: (note, the snippet won't work because it's running in a sandbox, try it in your own site and it should work)